# Mongoose array won't sort

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, sorting

A mongodb Document contains an array. When retrieved to the front-end with mongoose and graphql, using .sort() on the array throws an error.

> Cannot assign to read only property '1' of object '[object Array]'

However, using .sort() on the exact same array (but hard coded this time) works.

What's happening here?!

```js
const c = [ { slug: 'first-element',
    position: 1,
    alphaPos: 'B',
    type: 'heading',
    data: 'first-el B' },
{ slug: 'second-element',
    position: 2,
    alphaPos: 'C',
    type: 'textarea',
    data: 'second-el C' },
{ slug: 'third-element',
    position: 3,
    alphaPos: 'A',
    type: 'textarea',
    data: 'third-el A' },
{ slug: 'third-b-element',
    position: 3,
    alphaPos: 'D',
    type: 'textarea',
    data: 'third-el-22222 D' } ]

    // 'content' is the same as 'c' but it comes from mongoose, 
    // it throws an error
    console.log('content ==', content.sort())

    // 'c' is hard coded, no error is thrown
    console.log('content ==', c.sort())

    // console.log(c) and console.log(content) output exactly the same  array
```

[EDIT: here's the mongo document]

```json
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a801422f1c5437466c5d285"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-02-11T10:00:02.800Z"),
        "id" : 1,
        "slug" : "interesting-story",
        "creatorId" : 3,
        "title" : "An interesting story",
        "image" : "/images/image1.jpg",
        "description" : "description",
        "content" : [ 
            {
                "slug" : "first-element",
                "position" : 1,
                "alphaPos" : "B",
                "type" : "heading",
                "data" : "first-el B"
            }, 
            {
                "slug" : "second-element",
                "position" : 2,
                "alphaPos" : "C",
                "type" : "textarea",
                "data" : "second-el C"
            }, 
            {
                "slug" : "third-element",
                "position" : 3,
                "alphaPos" : "A",
                "type" : "textarea",
                "data" : "third-el A"
            }, 
            {
                "slug" : "third-b-element",
                "position" : 3,
                "alphaPos" : "D",
                "type" : "textarea",
                "data" : "third-el-22222 D"
            }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
    }
```

Here is the schema

```js
const postSchema = new Schema({
    id: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
    slug: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    creatorId: { type: Number, required: true },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    image: { type: String, required: false },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    content: { type: Array, required: false },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Because those are 2 different sorts, depends on what you call sort. If you call it on array ("hardcoded") it uses default sort function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort and if you cant call it on mongodocument object type without writing sort function.

To use mongoose sort you have to apply it while you're building the query

`collection.find().sort().then(...)`

Comment: thanks but as I mentionned the array is contained inside the document, as a field which is an array. If content were an object, .sort() works perfectly with Object.keys(content).sort(). When doing console.log(content) I can clearly see the sort() in __  proto __

Comment: @Sbe88 maybe try calling .toObject() on it

Comment: Thx, but outputs error: content.toObject is not a function. PS: in the meantime my guess is that the schema is wrong... any idea? Tried several things like type: Schema.Types.Mixed, type: [] but nothing does it yet

Comment: I mean to call toObject directly on mongodocument `(doc.toObject)` not on `doc.content`

Comment: How have you retrieved your document?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone encounters the same error, I still can't explain it but the array is considered as an object where indexes are the keys...

I'd be interested if someone has an explanation on this behavior (related to graphql? to mongoose? maybe to graphql-type-json package?).

So to sort it, here's what I'm doing (outputs an array).

```js
Object.keys(content).sort(a=>1).reduce((_sortedObj, key) => {
    _sortedObj.push(content[key])
    return _sortedObj
    }, [])
```